# How to display only one clock pointer in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create an analog clock from scratch using C#, and I'm a little stuck at this point.

I have this code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int seconde = DateTime.Now.Second;
     spx = cx + (int)(length * Math.Sin(Math.PI * seconde / 30));
     spy = cy - (int)(length * Math.Cos(Math.PI * seconde / 30));
     a = new Point(spx, spy);

     g.DrawLine(pen, m, a);
}
```

There are more variables in the form load but this is general how i draw the line for the second pointer on the clock. My problem is that it does exactly what i want. But after 60 seconds, I have 60 lines. How do I just display the good pointer line and/or delete the old lines.

Sorry if the answer to my problem is just easy. But I cant really find anything I understand as an answer.

Comment: You need to repaint the background of the clock every second before painting the new line, to remove the old line.

Comment: @ZoharPeled so when i have al three of the pointers (sec, min, hour) i need to safe those possitions and repaint them every second O.o?

Comment: If you are going to do it with winforms, yes.

Comment: That's how Windows *paints* with `WM_PAINT`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381401(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ZoharPeled ah oke thx. ill try thanks for pushing me into an direction. if u put ur command in an answer ill upvote it and accept it. :) after all i asked for an method to do it not the full sollution :D

Comment: [Analog Clock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40539578/3110834)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repaint the background of the clock every second before painting the new line, to remove the old line.
Of course, that would mean that for every paint of the seconds hand (or pointer) you will need to also paint the minutes hand and the hours hand, since both of them will also be deleted.

This is because winforms does not have the concept of painting in layers - everything gets painted on a single surface - so you have to first delete the old painting before you can paint a new one.

Comment: `g.Clear(Color.White);` Thank you used this now it works. :)

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: Winform cannot draw layer in a control but you can create layer with multiple control. If you overlap 4 controls with same dimensions, the background will refresh once in it's lifetime, the hour will refresh once per hours...etc. so painting in controls instead of background of the window would be faster as it will cut alot. on 24 hours thats 345,000 redraw in the background while 1 control for each layer will generate 87,865 redraw which is 400% faster.

Comment: Not in winforms, since it does not support true transparency. A transparent control in winforms actually draws it's parent control background to mimic transparency.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int spx, spy, length;
    private Pen pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 0.5f);
    private Point a,m;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Refresh(); // force redraw
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        length = Math.Min(e.ClipRectangle.Height, e.ClipRectangle.Width) / 2;

        if (length != 0) // can't draw when there's no space
        {
            m = new Point(e.ClipRectangle.Width / 2, e.ClipRectangle.Height / 2);

            int seconde = DateTime.Now.Second;
            spx = m.X + (int)(length * Math.Sin(Math.PI * seconde / 30));
            spy = m.Y - (int)(length * Math.Cos(Math.PI * seconde / 30));
            a = new Point(spx, spy);

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, m, a);
        }
    } 
}
```

I was taught to draw in OnPaint of Winforms controls.
Guess there are many different approaches.

By doing it this way you don't have to clear your graphics manually. This happens when the control is invalidated.

Comment: hmm, i see what u have done there. but to be honest. i think ill stay with the manual refresh method. just becouse i understand it more than this. thx for the answer tho ill look in to this later on.