# How do I make an analog clock using winforms in F#?

Tags: winforms, f#, real-time-clock

I have to create an analog clock using winforms in F#. The clock needs also to have a label showing date and time in digital form. I have figured how make the label with time and date, as well as drawing the circle and the clockhands, but I'm having trouble with how i'm gonna implement the timer function to the clock hands. So they move, and move to what the time is right now.

I don't know how to call the things i need in the third last line.
Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?
Because as it stands right now I have no idea how to it.

```
open System  
open System.Windows.Forms  
open System.ComponentModel  
open System.Drawing  

// ********* Winforms specifics *********
let win = new Form()
win.ClientSize <- Size (400, 400)

/// ********* Working Digital Clock *********
// make a label to show time
let digitalTimerLabel = new Label ()
win.Controls.Add digitalTimerLabel
digitalTimerLabel.Width <- 200
digitalTimerLabel.Location <- new Point (140,300)
digitalTimerLabel.Text <- string System.DateTime.Now // get present time and date

// make a timer and link to label
let timer = new Timer ()
timer.Interval <- 1000 // create an event every 1000 millisecond
timer.Enabled <- true // activiate the timer
timer.Tick.Add (fun e ->
digitalTimerLabel.Text <- string System.DateTime.Now
win.Invalidate()
)

// ********* Translate the clock *********
let translate (d : Point) (arr : Point []) : Point [] =
    let add (d : Point) (p : Point) : Point =
        Point (d.X + p.X, d.Y + p.Y)
    Array.map (add d) arr

// ********* Rotate the clock hands *********
let rotate (theta : float) (arr : Point []) : Point [] =
        let toInt = int << round
        let rot (t : float) (p : Point) : Point =
            let (x, y) = (float p.X, float p.Y)
            let (a, b) = (x * cos t - y * sin t, x * sin t + y * cos t)
            Point (toInt a, toInt b)
        Array.map (rot theta) arr

/// ********* ClockHands (Ur-visere) *********
let myPaint (e : PaintEventArgs) : unit =
    // HourHand
    let black = new Pen (Color.Black,Width=2.0f)
    let hourHand =
    //   [bot cord]    [top cord]
        [|Point (0,0);Point (0,-45)|]
    e.Graphics.DrawLines (black, hourHand)

    // MinuteHand
    let red = new Pen (Color.Red,Width=4.0f)
    let minuteHand =
    //   [bot cord]    [top cord]
        [|Point (0,0);Point (0,-20)|]
    e.Graphics.DrawLines (red, minuteHand)

    // SecondHand
    let green = new Pen (Color.Green,Width=1.0f)
    let secondHand =
    //   [bot cord]    [top cord]
        [|Point (0,0);Point (0,-20)|]
    e.Graphics.DrawLines (green, secondHand)

    // Circle
    let circleBlack = new Pen(Color.Black,Width=4.0f)
    let circle =
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(circleBlack,-100.0f,-100.0f,200.0f,200.0f)
    circle

    // CenterDot
    let CenterDotBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)
    let center =
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(CenterDotBrush,-2.5f,-2.5f,5.0f,5.0f)
    center

    let dt = DateTime.Now
    let s = dt.Second
    let m = dt.Minute
    let h = dt.Hour
    let newS = rotate (float s/60.0*2.0*System.Math.PI) secondHand
    let newM = rotate (float m/60.0*2.0*System.Math.PI) minuteHand
    let newH = rotate (float h/12.0*2.0*System.Math.PI) hourHand
    let finalS = translate (Point (200, 200)) secondHand
    let finalM = translate (Point (200, 200)) minuteHand
    let finalH = translate (Point (200, 200)) hourHand
    ()

win.Paint.Add myPaint

Application.Run win // start event - loop
```

Comment: You can find a C# example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40539030/3110834).

Comment: Did you write code from Q by yourself?

Comment: @FoggyFinder What? Made a new version btw.

Comment: @RezaAghaei The problem just is that i’m new to coding, so I can’t understand C# yet. Don’t know how it works.

Comment: I asked because there had [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301434/how-do-i-create-an-analog-clock-using-winforms-in-f) .

Comment: @FoggyFinder Didn't know there were a similar question.
And I have written it all by myself. 
Where some of the stuff I use is from the book, which we may use in our code (the digital timer label, timer, rotate function and translate function).
It's a task from my university i'm attending. (The last task)
And now I just can't seem to work out how to call the things in the third last line.

Comment: oh, so you have strong restriction to use only WinForm, right?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Yes, also have sorted it out :D It works now :) With a little extra tweeks here and there.

Comment: congrats, post it as an answer - there is nothing bad to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted it out. It works now:

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Drawing  

// ********* Winforms specifics *********
// Extended the default Form to avoid display flickered
type SmoothForm() as x =
    inherit Form()
    do x.DoubleBuffered <- true

let win = new SmoothForm()
win.ClientSize <- Size (400, 400)

/// ********* Digital Clock *********
// make a label to show time
let digitalTimerLabel = new Label ()
win.Controls.Add digitalTimerLabel
digitalTimerLabel.Width <- 200
digitalTimerLabel.Location <- Point (150,320)

// Timer
let timer = new Timer ()
timer.Interval <- 1000 // create an event every 1000 millisecond
timer.Enabled <- true // activiate the timer
timer.Tick.Add (fun _e ->
    digitalTimerLabel.Text <- string System.DateTime.Now
    win.Invalidate()
)

// ********* Translate function *********
let translate (d : Point) (arr : Point []) : Point [] =
    let add (d : Point) (p : Point) : Point =
        Point (d.X + p.X, d.Y + p.Y)
    Array.map (add d) arr

// ********* Rotate the clock hands *********
let rotate (theta : float) (arr : Point []) : Point [] =
    let toInt = int << round
    let rot (t : float) (p : Point) : Point =
        let (x, y) = (float p.X, float p.Y)
        let (a, b) = (x * cos t - y * sin t, x * sin t + y * cos t)
        Point (toInt a, toInt b)
    Array.map (rot theta) arr


/// ********* ClockHands (Ur-visere) *********
let myPaint (e : PaintEventArgs) : unit =
    // HourHand
    let black = new Pen (Color.Black,Width=4.0f)
    let hourHand = 
        [|Point (0,0); Point (0,-60)|]

    // MinuteHand
    let red = new Pen (Color.Red,Width=4.0f)
    let minuteHand =
        [|Point (0,0);Point (0,-90)|]

    // SecondHand
    let green = new Pen (Color.Green,Width=1.0f)
    let secondHand =
        [|Point (0,0);Point (0,-90)|]

    // Circle
    let circleBlack = new Pen(Color.Black,Width=4.0f)
    let circle =
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(circleBlack,100.0f,100.0f,200.0f,200.0f)
    circle

    //Circle color
    let circlecolorBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightSalmon)
    let circle =
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(circlecolorBrush,100.0f,100.0f,200.0f,200.0f)
    circle

    // CenterDot
    let centerDotBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)
    let center =
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(centerDotBrush,197.5f,197.5f,5.0f,5.0f)
    center

    // Time
    let dt = DateTime.Now
    let s = dt.Second
    let m = dt.Minute
    let h = dt.Hour

    // Make Rotation
    let secondHand = rotate (float s/60.0*2.0*System.Math.PI) secondHand
    let minuteHand = rotate (float m/60.0*2.0*System.Math.PI) minuteHand
    let hourHand   = rotate (float h/12.0*2.0*System.Math.PI) hourHand
    // Make Translate (Moving Point)
    let secondHand = translate (Point (200, 200)) secondHand
    let minuteHand = translate (Point (200, 200)) minuteHand
    let hourHand   = translate (Point (200, 200)) hourHand
    e.Graphics.DrawLines (black, hourHand)
    e.Graphics.DrawLines (red,   minuteHand)
    e.Graphics.DrawLines (green, secondHand)

win.Paint.Add myPaint

Application.Run win // start event - loop
```